# How to train a model in C++ with tensorflow?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I tried to trained a experiment with deep learning model.
I found that tensorflow is the best way to do this.
But there is problem that tensorflow need to be writen in python.
And my program contain many loops.Like this..

```
for i=1~2000
 for j=1~2000
```

I know this is a big drawback for python.
It's very slow than c.
I know tensorfow has a C++ API, but it's not clear.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/index.html
(This is the worst Specification I have ever looked)
Can someone give me an easy example in that?
All I need is two simple code.
One is how to create a graph.
The other is how to load this graph and run it.
I really eager need this.Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Running the computation in TensorFlow is not the same as doing it in python, even if you're calling TensorFlow from python. You build the graph, then execute it. But the execution happens in TensorFlow itself, which is very fast. It's not using interpreted python except as 'glue' code.

Comment: I know what you mean.The deep model code is fast enough.But I have another code which have to write in many loops.(Reinforcement learning).It's a recursive function.

Comment: I see. Hope the C++ works for you. If it came down to having to use the python API, might be possible to accelerate using cython, as a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so easy, but it is possible.
First, you need to create tensorflow graph in python and save it in file.
This article may help you
https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f#.krslipabt

Second, you need to compile libtensorflow, link it to your program (you need tensorflow headers as well, so it's a bit tricky) and load the graph from the file.
This article may help you this time
https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-tensorflow-graphs-via-host-languages-be10fd81876f#.p9s69rn7u